# Не работает метод $(window).resize();

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function _resize() {
    var width = $("body").width();
    if (width === 964) {
        $("#Equalizer").css("margin", "0px");
    }
    else
        $("#Equalizer").css("margin", "auto");
}
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    _resize();
    $(window).resize(_resize)
});
```

нужно при каждом изминении размеров окна отслеживать размер body и в соответствии со случаем устанавливать margin. Но дело в том что событие не сробатывает.

```css
#Equalizer {
    margin:auto;
    width: 60%;
    font-family:Consola Mono;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function _resize() {
            var width = $("body").width();
            if (width === 964) {
                $("#Equalizer").css("margin", "0px");
            }
            else
                $("#Equalizer").css("margin", "auto");
        }
        $(window).ready(function ()
        {
            _resize();
            $(document).resize(_resize)
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Equalizer">
        <p>
            С другой стороны постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки дальнейших направлений развития. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия.
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет важную роль в формировании систем массового участия. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому что вы вызываете `_resize` до того как передали

Comment: @Grundy простите опечатка, но всёравно не работает

Comment: Чем вам css не угодил?

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы вызываете `_resize` до того как передали в виде параметра, нужно передавать без `()`

```
$(window).resize(_resize)
```

**UPDATE**

Для проверки выполняется ли обработчик или нет - добавьте в функцию вывод в консоль, например

```
console.log('resize func');
```

Кроме того внутри функции у вас стоит жесткое условие

```
 if (width === 964) {
```

это значит что `margin:0` будет выставляться только в случае точного совпадени размера. Возможно вы хотели использовать тут `<`

**UPDATE2**
В разметке которую вы приложили вы перепутали местами document и window

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    _resize();
    $(window).resize(_resize)
});
```

[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/53ebSO6chQJ63y1Mg9oM?p=preview) - в консоли видно что функция вызывается.

Comment: Всёравно не работает

Comment: @Алексей посмотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: не знаю почему но событие не вызывается,в консоли должно быть как минимум две записи, а там одна

Comment: @Алексей, где и как вы проверяли?

Comment: я не понял конечно почему но я подключил google'вский jquery, вместо предлагаемого microsoft и всё зарабатола

Comment: @Алексей, нужно смотреть вашу разметку: ту которую вы привели в пример вы пытаетесь подключить два раза jQuery, причем первый тег скрипт лежит до `<!DOCTYPE>`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31790/discussion-between-grundy-and-).